# Okhttp NoClassDefFoundError while uploading aar package on Github

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, okhttp, aar

I am trying to upload an aar file on Github but after the package is implmeneted, I keep getting the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor;`

Here is my build.gradle for the library

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

def githubProperties = new Properties()
githubProperties.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("github.properties")))

def getVersionName = { ->
    return "1.0.10"
}

def getArtifactId = { ->
    return "example-android-sdk" // Replace with library name ID
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0")
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.6.0"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
}


publishing {
    publications {
        bar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.example' // Replace with group ID
            artifactId getArtifactId()
            version getVersionName()
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${getArtifactId()}-release.aar")
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            /** Configure path of your package repository on Github
             ** Replace GITHUB_USERID with your/organisation Github userID
             ** and REPOSITORY with the repository name on GitHub
             */
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/shubham/exampleapp")
            credentials {
                /** Create github.properties in root project folder file with
                 ** gpr.usr=GITHUB_USER_ID & gpr.key=PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
                 ** Set env variable GPR_USER & GPR_API_KEY if not adding a properties file**/

                username = githubProperties['gpr.usr'] ?: System.getenv("GPR_USER")
                password = githubProperties['gpr.key'] ?: System.getenv("GPR_API_KEY")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The upload happens using these two commands:

```
./gradlew lazyclick:assemble --stacktrace
./gradlew lazyclick:publish --stacktrace
```

Once the aar package is uploaded I implement inside my build.gradle(app)

```
implementation 'com.example:example-android-sdk:1.0.10'
```

Here is the Proguard rules I added:

```
# OkHttp
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class okhttp3.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.internal.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature

# Okio
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class okio.** { *; }


-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *;}
```

But when I run the app I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor;
```

Please help me in this case. This is the first time I am uploading the aar on Github.